# Download solution package?

Tags: sandbox-solution

I was reading this article by Vesu
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119071517/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx#stepbystep)

and at the end of article he posted the solution file. But my company blocks access to that domain. Can anyone please email me a copy or posted someplace where I can download the solution package?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

https://sites.google.com/site/omlinfiles/Contoso.Intranet.WebTemplates.zip?attredirects=0&d=1

Comment: WOW. you are sooooooo cool. I thought no would do that. I truly appreciate it. Man you made my day. Thanks Omlin....